Unsure if spatial Autocorrelation is present or not
I built a classic linear model with 1000 data points for which I have coordinates. I thus checked for the presence of spatial autocorrelation with a bubble plot of the residuals and with Moran's I test:
This is the result of the test:
$observed
-0.007053622
$expected
-0.001251564
$sd
0.0009352079
$p.value
5.50355e-10
And this is the bubble plot of the residuals:

So far my interpretation is that, despite the Moran's I value being close to zero, the significant p-value suggests that the observed spatial pattern is not purely random, and that there is a slight tendency towards negative spatial autocorrelation.
Nevertheless, although the p-value of the test is highly significant, if I look at the difference between the expected and observed values, the difference is very small, -0.007 compared to -0.001 (also accounting that Moran.I value ranges from -1 to +1). If I then look at the bubble plot, I do some randomness in the distribution of the residuals, I don't really see a structure in the way the residuals are distributed (although in the lower part of the plot, the bubbles are a bit condensed, making it difficult to understand what is going on there). So, do you think I have spatial autocorrelation or not?
Could it be that even a small observed Moran's I value can be statistically significant if the sample size is large, making the test more sensitive to small deviations from randomness?.
Am I interpreting it correctly (meaning I can avoid "handling" the spatial autocorrelation) or should I dive deeper into it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Moran's I is limited, because it's a single statistic.  The go-to method to consider is variography.  Variograms characterize spatial correlation in much greater detail and provide quantitative insight to guide further analyses.
